# Can I create a bean from a SpEL expression directly?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-el, spring-bean

I have a SpEL expression that generates a SpEL list. (The result type is actually a Java array, but no sense quibbling.)

I want "promote" the result of my SpEL expression to a bean in my Spring XML beans configuration file. One way to do this that works is to construct an ArrayList bean and supply the array as a `constructor-arg` like so:

```
<bean name="myList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ my SpEL expression here }"/>
</bean>
```

This seems a bit cumbersome to me. Is there a one-liner that does the same thing and lets me put the array directly into a bean without having to wrap it in a newly-constructed `ArrayList` bean?

If not, is there a terser or cleaner syntax for doing what I'm doing now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the same issue I have with the bean definition for just `java.lang.String`:

```
<bean id="myString" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="foo"/>
</bean>
```

And I live with that already for a long time. So simple to try to hack and don't do the real work :-).

How about to try this:

```
<util:list id="myList">
    <value>#{ my SpEL expression here }</value>
</util:list>
```

From other side you can just go to the JavaConfig and be free from this XML crutches. You should understand that XML definition is a bit restricted to the XML language boundaries and forgive him some inconveniences.